# Thymeleaf exception when jar with root permission

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a small website which I have developed with normal user(ubuntu) for port 80.

package is installed

```
mvn clean install
```

If i run application using sudo cmd

```
sudo jar -jar /home/yogi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-web-spring-security/1.0/spring-boot-web-spring-security-1.0.jar ut
```

Here "yogi" is a normal user, using sudo command to listern at port 80.

It starts properly but while loading the thymeleaf causing exception, For which the logs are below:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206) ~[websocket-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception states that the Thymeleaf template that you are looking for is not in its classpath. Make sure that `login` template exists in the application classpath.